# Parental control software

Tags: parents, computer

I need some advice from other parents. I’m working on a [project][1] about adult toys. Under the current virus situation, I’ve been working from home, so I’ve been using my private computer for work. A couple of days ago my daughter’s computer broke down and now for some time I’ll have to share mine with her. But I don’t want Sarah to run across my working articles. So my question, is there any good parental control software, that you can recommend?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a software recommendation question and not on topic.

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't know where to ask it

Comment: I don't know that there is a right place.  [Super User](https://superuser.com) is the right place to ask how to use your computer operating system and things along those lines, but it absolutely does not accept software recommendation questions; I'm not sure that [softwarerecs.se] would be correct, either, but perhaps?

Comment: Martha, let me be blunt: Linking to your project is absolutely irrelevant to the question (which is off-topic anyway). Re-introducing said link will be seen as spam and treated accordingly.

Comment: [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) seems a good starting point.

Comment: @Stephie You might also want to remove the markup around the place the link was in the text of the post, as well as the URL. I tried to do it myself but removing the characters was too short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way would simply be to create a separate account for her and [limit her access to your files](https://superuser.com/questions/1115595/windows-10-how-do-i-lock-limit-another-users-access-to-my-folders).  This also allows her to have her own environment for school work.

Comment: Thank you, actually that seems to be the best way out.